# Radio button checked when open modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

```
$('#event-modal input[name="event_type"]:checked').val(event ? event.name : '');
```

im having a radio button to be checked when user open the modal. the value is in string format. how to do this?

It has 3 possible value. "Public Holiday" or "Working Day" or "Weekend"

Comment: Is that even Java? It sure doesn't look like any Java that I know

Comment: sorry, it supposed to be javascript

Comment: What is the value of `event.name`?

Comment: the value can be "Working Day" or "Weekend" or "Public Holiday"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set the value and force it to be checked:

```
$('#event-modal input[name="event_type"]').val(event.name).prop('checked',true);
```